# Highcharts can't read data with commas

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a problem on putting commas on the amount that I've be pulling from my DB.

I've added 'commaSeparateNumber function' and I works, but the problem is Highcharts can't read numbers with commas. I've tried using parsefloat but didn't work for me. Here's my function:

```
  function Filltbl(data) {

                        $.each(data, function () {
                            var html = "<tr><td>" + this.SampleNo + "</td><td>" + this.SC_Com + "</td><td>" + this.SC_AP + "</td><td>" + this.SC_Cer + "</td><td>" + this.SC_Pd + "</td></tr>";
                            $('#datatable').append(commaSeparateNumber(html));

                        });                   
                    }
```

And this one is for commaSeparateNumber function:

```
  function commaSeparateNumber(val) {
                while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())) {
                    val = val.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
                }
                return val;
            }
```

And this is what I receive from Highcharts:

```
Highcharts Error #14

String value sent to series.data, expected Number

This happens if you pass in a string as a data point, for example in a setup like this:

series: [{
    data: ["3", "5", "1", "6"]
}]
Highcharts expects the data values to be numbers. The most common reason for this is that data is parsed from CSV or from a XML source, and the implementer forgot to run parseFloat on the parsed value.

For performance reasons internal type casting is not performed, and only the first value is checked (since 2.3).
```

Comment: Can you please add a JSFiddle with your code? It's much easier to get help like that.

Comment: Also, your `data` array needs to have numbers, not strings. For e.g: [1,2,3,4] rather than ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

Comment: Yes, I have.= and it works fine. My only problem is when I use the commaSeparatedfunction, my HIghChart doesn't show.

Comment: Can you add a JSFiddle that runs your code so we can see where it fails?

Comment: Can't run it on JS fiddle sir, since I' am currently using web service. But it fails here: $('#datatable').append(commaSeparateNumber(html));

Comment: Where do you use `parsefloat` and why doesn't it work for you. I cannot find any `parsefloat` in your code.

Comment: I deleted it because it doesn't work. But I add it like this:                         $('#datatable').append(parseFloat(html));

Comment: So works well at this moment or not ?